# Parsing through XML and dump values into Excel using UIPATH

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization, uipath

I would like to dump data for only BMW cars to excel. I do have thousands of XML files and a number of entries will vary (in this case 3, it could from 0 to 5).

Considering this scenario, I have to increment counter or transaction item in UIPATH. But to start with I would like to dump data into excel for this XML file and I am expecting output given in the attached image

```
    <country>
                <state>Texas</state>
                    <cars>        
                                 <brand>BMW</brand>
                                 <model>X1</model>
                                 <unit>210000</unit>        
                    </cars>
                    <cars>        
                                <brand>BMW</brand>
                                <model>X6</model>
                                <unit>210000</unit>     
                    </cars>
                    <cars>        
                                <brand>BMW</brand>
                                <model>X7</model>
                                 <unit>210000</unit>        
                    </cars>
                    <cars>        
                                 <brand>Ford</brand>
                                 <model>mustang</model>
                                 <unit>319000</unit>        
                    </cars>
                    <cars>        
                                 <brand>Volvo</brand>
                                <model>XC90</model>
                                 <unit>91100</unit>     
                    </cars> 
    </country>
```

**Output - **

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few possible approaches and which one you choose depends on how comfortable you are with .NET (using the [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument) class, more details in the UiPath KB [here](https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/how-to-iterate-and-read-xml-documents)).

If you would prefer to avoid that you can try is the following sequence using only the `Execute XPath` function:

```
 1. For each XML file
 2. ... Get number of BMWs: count(//cars/brand[text()='BMW'])
 3. ... Loop that amount of times
 4. ... ... Get each individual value for that car: string(//cars[brand[text()='BMW']][i]/model)
    ... ... ... (replace the i for the loop number)
 5. ... ... Write that to Excel
 6. ... ... Repeat the previous command also for unit
```